# Find all matching elements in std::list

Tags: c++, c++11, stdlist

I was wondering if there's any built-in or well-established way (i.e. via lambda) to go through the elements of an std::list and find all the ones that match a given value? I know I can iterate through all of them, but I thought I'd ask if there's a way to get an iterator that iterates through just the elements that match a given criteria? My sample below only gives me the iterator to the first matching element.

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> List;
    List.push_back(100);
    List.push_back(200);
    List.push_back(300);
    List.push_back(100);
    int findValue = 100;

    auto it = std::find_if(List.begin(), List.end(), [findValue](const int value)
    {
        return (value == findValue);
    });

    if (it != List.end())
    {
        for (; it != List.end(); ++it)
        {
            printf("%d\n", * it);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Repeatedly call `find_if` to find the remaining matches, just increment the begin iterator prior to each call (assuming the last call resulted in a match). If you do this often enough, write a function. And if all you're doing is using `operator==` within the predicate, there's no need for `find_if`, `find` does that for you.

Comment: *"if there's a way to get an iterator that iterates through just the elements that match a given criteria"* Maybe [Filter Iterators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`std::find_if` is a generalisation of `std::find` for when you need a function to check for the elements you want, rather than a simple test for equality. If you just want to do a simple test for equality then there's no need for the generalised form, and the lambda just adds complexity and verbosity. Just use `std::find(begin, end, findValue)` instead:

```
std::vector<std::list<int>::const_iterator> matches;
auto i = list.begin(), end = list.end();
while (i != end)
{
  i = std::find(i, end, findValue);
  if (i != end)
    matches.push_back(i++);
}
```

But rather than calling `find` in a loop I'd just write the loop manually:

```
std::vector<std::list<int>::const_iterator> matches;
for (auto i = list.begin(), toofar = list.end(); i != toofar; ++i)
  if (*i == findValue)
    matches.push_back(i);
```

Comment: wouldn't `std::copy()` check the whole list only once O(N), while yours would do O(x*N)? Better look the other answers too :) @smac89 has a good one bellow

Comment: @Paiusco why would mine not be O(N)? each std::find starts where the previous find stopped.

Answer (score 38):

#### Updated answer

With the advent of C++20 just around the corner, the standard library has now introduced the concept of [ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) which comes with view adapters and are simply lazy views over collections and their transformations.

This means you can now have an "*iterator*" which can be used to obtain a filtered and transformed view of an underlying container/collection, without having to create several iterators or even allocate memory.

Having said that, this is a way to create a view over just the filtered elements of your list:

```
// List is your std::list
auto matching_100 = List | std::views::filter([](auto &v) {
  return v == 100;
});
```

How sweet is that? All you need to use all that?

```
#include <ranges>
```

[Try it out](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Nxpg3NXYVfs41te0)

---

### Previous answer

Using [copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) and [iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator):

```
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::list<int> List;
    List.push_back(100);
    List.push_back(200);
    List.push_back(300);
    List.push_back(100);
    int findValue = 100;

    std::copy_if(List.begin(), List.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"), [&](int v) {
        return v == findValue;
    });
    return 0;
}
```

If you don't want to directly output the results and want to fill another container with the matches:

```
std::vector<int> matches;
std::copy_if(List.begin(), List.end(), std::back_inserter(matches), [&](int v) {
    return v == findValue;
});
```

Answer (score 19):

[`boost::filter_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html) allows you to work with only the elements of a iterable that satisfy a predicate. Given a predicate `Pred` and a container `Cont`,

```
auto begin_iter = boost::make_filter_iterator(Pred, std::begin(Cont), std::end(Cont));
auto end_iter = boost::make_filter_iterator(Pred, std::end(Cont), std::end(Cont));
```

You can now use `begin_iter` and `end_iter` as if they were the begin and end iterators of a container containing only those elements of `Cont` that satisfied `Pred`. Another added advantage is that you can wrap the iterators in a [`boost::iterator_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/range/doc/utility_class.html#iter_range) and use it in places which expect a iterable object, like a range-based `for` loop like this:

```
auto range = boost::make_iterator_range(begin_iter, end_iter);
for(auto x : range) do_something(x);
```

In particular, setting `Pred` to a functor(could be a lambda) that checks for equality with your fixed value will give you the iterators you need.

Comment: #include <boost/iterator/filter_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/range/iterator_range.hpp>

Comment: Question was about std::list; an answer contained within the standard library would be legit.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) lets you simply move all elements matching the predicate to the front of the container (first partition). The return value is an iterator pointing to the first element of the second partition (containing the non matching elements). That's pretty much all you need to "filter" a container.