# Searching for corresponding structs inside a large container

Tags: c++, struct, deque

I have a large container of structs

```
std::deque<MyStruct> dq;
```

My struct has a few properties of type string

```
struct MyStruct {
    std::string what, when, where;
};
```

I want to find all the structs for which MyStruct.what = "SomeString". Whenever I find one of these,
I need to find a corresponding struct somewhere in the container. This corresponding struct 
will have CorrespondingStruct.what = "SomeOtherString" and CorrespondingStruct.when = MyStruct.when.
The corresponding struct can be before or after the original struct. There is only 1 corresponding struct
for each original struct.

When the corresponding struct is found, I want to find a third struct that will be a little further below,
and for which FinalStruct.what = "DesiredString".
When I finally find this struct, I want to get its index so I can do some operations and rearranging.

At the moment, I can't think of any way to do this other than a bunch of nasty nested loops:

```
findCorrespondingIndex(std::deque<MyStruct>& dq) {
    for (auto it = dq.rbegin(); it != dq.rend(); ++it) {
        if ((*it).what == "SomeString") {
            for (auto itt = dq.rbegin(); itt != dq.rend(); ++itt) {
                if ((*itt).what == "SomeOtherString" && (*itt).when == (*it).when) {
                    int index = std::distance(dq.begin(), itt) - 1;
                    while (dq[index].what != "DesiredString") index--;
                    // do stuff
                    continue; // break out of inner for loop to look for the next MyStruct.what = "SomeString"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant/simpler way to write this in C++?

Comment: I don't know if you force to use deque, but if you are free for choosing container look at this link for vector and list https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454831/find-all-matching-elements-in-stdlist

Comment: @samini The data is provided as deque, but I suppose I can copy the contents to a different container as needed. That link looks promising, I'll take a careful look at it.