# std::find, alternative method that returns all found values instead of just the first for vector where duplicate exists

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, duplicates, stdvector

I've been doing some testing with std::find in vectors with duplicate values

I have noticed that std::find will always return the first value out of a duplicate e.g. when I look for the value 2 in the vector `vecDup`:

```
std::vector<int> vecDup = { 0, 5, 1, 2, 2, 4 };

auto valIterator = (std::find(vecDup.begin(), vecDup.end(), 2));
if (valIterator != vecDup.end()) {
    int value = (*valIterator);
    int valueIndex = std::distance(vecDup.begin(), valIterator);
    std::cout << "Duplicate value: " << value << " at index " << valueIndex << std::endl;
}
```

> Duplicate value: 2 at index 3

The docs states that std::find:
Returns an iterator to the first element in the range [first,last) that compares equal to val. If no such element is found, the function returns last.

So I suppose std::find cannot be used to find multiple values. So my question is, what (if any) std methods can I use to get these multiple values in one form or the other? The only output I need is some kind of reference to the indices where these duplicates exist.

Edit

I know this isn't a particularly difficult problem and can be achieved quite easily using for loops. I just thought that this might be a common issue and that there might be some kind of built in method that is already made to achieve this.

Comment: Hint.  If you want an operation to happen multiple times, you can use a loop to do so.

Comment: Answers go in the answer section, even if they are your own answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all matching elements in std::list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454831/find-all-matching-elements-in-stdlist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I have you correct, you want to have different iterator pointing to every duplicate of a particular element in the vector. Then, always go for the good ol' for loop:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator> vec_of_dup_iters;
auto it = vecDup.begin();
for(it = std::find(it, vecDup.end(), elem); it != vecDup.end(); it = std::find(it, vecDup.end(), elem)) {
    vec_of_dup_iters.push_back(it++);
}
```

---

But, instead of storing these many vectors, I suggest storing indices instead and generating vectors whenever needed:

```
std::vector<unsigned> vec_of_indices;
for(size_t index = 0; index < vecDup.size(); index++) {
    if(vecDup.at(index) == elem) {
        vec_of_indices.push_back(index);
    }
}
```

And then add the index to `vecDup.begin()` to generate the iterator

Comment: Thank you this looks good. What would the O() be for this?

Comment: @Tom, Ask yourself this ( I won't spoonfeed ;) ). How many times is the code iterating over the vector? Are there nested iterations in each iteration (implicit/explicit)? You will get the complexity yourself :) ................. Spoiler: its O(vecDup.size()) ;)

Answer (score 3):

> Can this be achieved using std::find

Yes. You can use the following algorithm:

```
Let It be an iterator to the beginning list
while It is not end
    Use std::find to search starting from It, and store result in It
    if It is not end
        add It to set of results (or the index)
        increment It
```

Instead, an old fashioned loop may be simpler:

```
for i in [0, vecDup.size()[
    if vecDup[i] matches the predicate
        add i to set of results
```